# Unit testing HFT stock prices - Asserts constantly fail due to price fluctuations

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, assert

For an application that retrieves live stock prices I find my unit test assertions returning false negatives due to price fluctuations between two calls that populate variables which hold the `expected` and `actual` test values.

While this is to be expected, I would love to hear different approaches as to how work around this issue. My initial thoughts was to allow for a margin of fluctuation (~2% difference between retrieved stock prices)

***This is the code making the Web request to Yahoo in order to retrieve a stock price.***

---

```
    public string makeWebRequest(string stockSymbol, string dataRequestID)
    {
        string request = webClient.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + stockSymbol + 
                                                  "&f=" + dataRequestID).Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\"", "");

        if (request.Equals("N/A") || request.Equals("0"))
            return "0.00";

        return request;
    }

    public string getPrice(string stockSymbol)
    {
        return makeWebRequest(stockSymbol, "l1");
    }
```

**This is the unit test which makes a "hard coded" (known to be successful) web request for the stock price and assigning the result to the `expected` variable. Afterwards, perform another call in order the retrieve the price only this time using the applications object.function then assigning it to the `actual` variable.**

***The delta between calls is of 300ms***

---

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void getPrice()
    {
        string expected = request.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + testSymbol + "&f=l1").Replace("\r\n", "").Replace("\"", "");
        string actual = yahoo.getPrice(testSymbol);

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }
```

---

Any Suggestions? Or should I just learn to live with it?

Comment: You shouldn't unit test with live data for precisely this reason.

Comment: I can see your point, yet I fail to convince myself that a false-negative unit test 50% of the time is worse than having no tests at all. Maybe it has not slapped me hard enough yet :|

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save what your call to server receives and then write unit test that verifies that you can parse that string. 
You can also write a test that verifies that you try to hit right url for specified symbol. Those would be unit tests. Your is integration test.

Comment: Very good point, since what I care about is to build the correct query URL, then I should just test the URL rather than the retrieved value. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to mock DownloadString method and return some known value (from a file or from hardcoded variable in the test).
Right now you are not only testing your code but also you internet connectivity, yahoo website  etc.